# Regex messes up syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax, syntax-highlighting

Am I missing something here? This regex is for email validation, and it looks like one of the forward slashes are throwing off the syntax highlighting.

[image]

```
var emailRegex = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;

var validEmail = emailRegex.test(newEmail.email);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to format this regular expression to prevent this from happening?

I was unable to find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably just escape the `/` in the regex. Otherwise the syntax highlighter thinks it closes the regex literal.

```
//-----------------------vv
var re = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
```

Or you could file a bug with whatever editor it is you're using.

---

Notice that the syntax highlighter on SO doesn't have an issue with the original.

```
var re = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
```